# How to create a Line Chart with markers in nvd3?

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I want to create a line chart with custom markers with nvd3.js library as shown in the following example:

[image]

Is there a way to configure the chart using the chart config object? or should I modify the `lineChart` from the nvd3 library to achieve this? if so, any clues on how should I update it?

Comment: By "markers", you're talking about changing the green triangles and red Xs, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct :)

Comment: Have you tried just using CSS?

Comment: nvd3 is using svg paths to render the markers.  They have a CSS class attach to all the markers.

Comment: You can override their CSS and/or attach pseudo-class elements to display what you want.

Comment: This is how the marker looks like: `<path d="M0,2.25675833.." style="stroke-width:132.46168994287655px" class="nv-point nv-point-3 nv-noninteractive hover" transform="translate(425.3333333333333,285)"></path>`  so I think overriding their CSS and/or attaching pseudo-class elements won't work.. I am afraid I will have to dig into the code and see where those paths and transform properties are generated.

Comment: or could I somehow replace the `d` path by a background image using CSS?